# how to set solaris locale

Tags: solaris, localization

I am getting the following errors when I execute some commands on Solaris 10.

`couldn't set locale correctly`

Output of locale command-

```
LANG=en_US
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Does LC_ALL need to be set? I don't have root on this machine.. can I specify locale in my rc files?

Comment: Which commands?

Comment: Running a perl script

Comment: So is this any Perl script or just one? If the latter, can you post the part of your script that is causing the error? LC_ALL is used for overriding the other settings.

Comment: Do not set both `LC_ALL` and the other `LC_` variables.  Either unset `LC_ALL`, or set it to a valid value and unset the others.

Comment: I see... this shows up intermittently... I cannot seem to find a trend.. I'll hunt for the next instance of this error and try to find more about the command causing the error

Comment: mark4o is correct - remove the LC_ALL setting if you've set the rest of the LC_* settings.

Answer (score 2):

Locale settings are done via environment variables - you don't need to edit system files unless you want to change the defaults for every process on the system.   The [locale(5)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5175/6mbba7f1a/index.html) and [environ(5)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5175/6mbba7evq/index.html) man pages have more details on the various variables that affect locale settings.

`locale -a` will show the installed locales so you can make sure you've set it to one that's actually there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `localeadm` to install additional locales.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your Solaris installation is missing packages with locales.  Try doing a full OS installation and then setting the locale.

Answer (score 0):

`locale -a` gives you the list of installed locales. I believe that list doesn't contain en_US entry, so try setting `LANG` to `"C"` as well, or override it with setting `LC_ALL` to `"C"`